# Query alterando join - SequelizeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Como poderia fazer essa query utilizando Sequelize?

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id != t2.t1_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer uma [raw query](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) e manter esse SQL que já tens. Segundo a [documentação](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) podes fazer isso com `sequelize.query`:

```
sequelize.query("SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id != t2.t1_id", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(function(results) {
    // aqui podes usar o results
  })
```